# passing a closure in a plugin extension in gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'd like to pass a closure as configuration for a plugin. Here is a minimal version of it:

```
package org.samuel.gradle.plugins

import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.Task

class TestPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  void apply(Project project) {

    project.extensions.create("testConfig", TestConfig)

    Task test = project.task("testTask") {
      doFirst {
        println "The message is already " + project.extensions.testConfig.message
        println "Trying to run closure " + project.extensions.testConfig.closure
        project.extensions.testConfig.closure()
        println "did it run?"
      }
    }
  }
}

class TestConfig {
  String message = "Testing ..."
  Closure closure = {
    println("running closure")
  }
}
```

This doesn't work, the closure is never evaluated (nor at configuration nor when I intend it to:

```
$ ./gradlew test
:buildSrc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileGroovy
:buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:classes
:buildSrc:jar
:buildSrc:assemble
:buildSrc:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:test UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:build
:testTask
The message is already Testing ...
Trying to run closure org.samuel.gradle.plugins.TestConfig$_closure1@5600ea3b
did it run?

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.569 secs
```

I think I am missing something about how gradle evaluates the contents of the extensions. Is it possible to somehow pass something via an extension and evaluate it in a task in the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is surprisingly *unimpressive*. Change the line for calling the closure to:

```
project.extensions.testConfig.closure.call()
```

Notice the use of `.call()` vs just calling `()`

Also noticed that this calls the closure:

```
println "Trying to run closure ${project.extensions.testConfig.closure}"
```

[Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56467564/why-does-directly-calling-groovy-closure-not-work-but-using-call-does)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will tentatively accept it as I assume it does work like that, but for the unlikely bystander: I cannot really verify this as I have not worked with gradle for quite some time now and the codebase related to this question belongs to a former employer