# Why does directly calling groovy closure not work, but using .call() does?

Tags: gradle, closures

This question relates to another question: [passing a closure in a plugin extension in gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172625/passing-a-closure-in-a-plugin-extension-in-gradle)

The solution was to call the closure with `.call()`.

Why does this work instead of directly calling the closure?

Comment: I suggest to tag question as `gradle` instead of `groovy` because in groovy there is no such problem... and gradle has own parser/compiler..